# PHP file upload form cannot submit a POST variable?

Tags: php, file, upload

I have a PHP file upload form with `method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"`

I am trying to do a `<input type = "hidden" name = 'something' value = "something"/>` along with the input for file upload, but I am not able to get the value of 'something' in the upload handling script like `$_POST['something']`

Is it not possible to use POST variables along with a file upload? Any other alternative on how I can pass information to the upload handling script?

Comment: This should work fine. Can you show the full HTML form, and the results of a `print_r[$_POST]`?

Answer (score 1):

First, having some consistency with which quotes you use would be a good first step.

Second, you have got the `enctype` correct, so what may be an issue is you've exceeded the servers `file upload size` or `post size` settings. Try upload a smaller file and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I had set a rather low post size setting to meet my need. Increased it now and I have it working.

Comment: Thanks mate, glad I helped :-) If you would like you can mark this answer as the one which solved your question by clicking the tick next to it. Happy coding :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use other inputs along with the file upload fields.

Ensure that:

- All fields are inside **form** tags
- Youdidn't misspell field names and array indexes
- You are using "double qutes" everywhere in your HTML (just in case)

To debug, try putting this code at the top of your script to see what is being passed:

```
echo '<xmp>';
print_r($_POST);
echo '</xmp>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but I'll post anyway... maybe I can help someone.

In my case the problem was the 'post_max_size' in php.ini.

Cheers.